# Me.Filter using String containing numerous values

Tags: ms-access, filter, vba

```
Private Sub cbtn_canceled_Click()
Me.Filter = "([status_code] Like 'BQ' OR [status_code] Like 'RG')"
Me.FilterOn = True
End Sub
```

Works fine but I need to return about 30 posibilties.  I have tried feeding a strFilter like this,

```
Dim strFilter As String
strFilter = "BQ,RQ,WS,WE"
Me.Filter = "([status_code] Like strFilter)"
```

I have tried lots of strFilter combos with no luck.  The OR statment needs to get in there somehow.

Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like is used with a wildcard character, such as '*****' meaning any sequence of characters. So

```
Me.Filter = "([status_code] Like 'BQ*' OR [status_code] Like 'RG*')"
```

would find any items that begin with either BQ or RG.

If you are looking for an exact match then you can use IN:

```
Me.Filter = "([status_code] IN('BQ','RG')"
```

So for

```
strFilter = "'BQ','RQ','WS','WE'"
```

you would use

```
Me.Filter = "([status_code] IN(" &  strFilter & ")"
```

You need to *concatenate* strFilter using ampersand (&), otherwise it would be looking for the word 'strFilter'.

Comment: Cut and pasted to my book of knowledge Andy.  Thanks for the explination as to me is more important than the solution.